# Get Nth class of an element having multiple class with out using .attr("class") in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a div with two classes, the first inner div

```
<div class="datacheck">
   <div class="classic_div_data customdataid_305">
     some values come here
   </div>
   <div class="optiondiv">
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to get a substring (here the number 305) from the second class(`customdataid_305`) of the first inner div. For this **need to get the classes.**

I wrote in jquery and succeed

```
var xyz= $($(".datacheck").find("div")[0]).attr("class").split(" ")[1]
```

from which I gets the class.

Is there any simpler approach for this.
I am searching for something like this `$(element).class()` probably returns an array of classes

Comment: Why don't you add a `data-*` attribute instead of adding a class? That smells like a bad design.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Vohuman I know, but I dont have permission to do that

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that gives you an *array* of classes, although the native DOM `classList` is close. But I don't think `classList` will make things much simpler.

I'd do this:

```
var xyz = $(".datacheck .classic_div_data").attr("class").match(/\bcustomdataid_(\d+)\b/);
xyz = xyz && xyz[1];
```

The regex extracts the numeric portion of the class, without being fragile (sensitive to whether the class is the first or second in the list of classes, for instance).

Example:

```js
var xyz = $(".datacheck .classic_div_data").attr("class").match(/\bcustomdataid_(\d+)\b/);
xyz = xyz && xyz[1];
console.log("xyz = '" + xyz + "'");
```

```html
<div class="datacheck">
   <div class="classic_div_data customdataid_305">
     some values come here
   </div>
   <div class="optiondiv">
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you can change the HTML, though, I wouldn't use a class for this at all, I'd us a `data-*` attribute instead:

```
<div class="classic_div_data" data-custom-id="305">
```

then

```
var xyz = $(".datacheck [data-custom-id]").attr("data-custom-id");
```

Example:

```js
var xyz = $(".datacheck [data-custom-id]").attr("data-custom-id"); 
console.log("xyz = '" + xyz + "'");
```

```html
<div class="datacheck">
   <div class="classic_div_data" data-custom-id="305">
     some values come here
   </div>
   <div class="optiondiv">
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the major problems you have with your current design is that if the order of the classes changes, or someone adds another class, your logic breaks. You're also getting a DOMElement from a jQuery object which you turn back in to a jQuery object again.

It would be a much better approach to use `data-*` attributes to store your custom data, like this:

```js
$('.classic_div_data').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).data('customdataid'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="datacheck">
  <div class="classic_div_data" data-customdataid="305">
    some values come here
  </div>
  <div class="optiondiv"></div>
</div>
<div class="datacheck">
  <div class="classic_div_data" data-customdataid="205">
    some more values come here
  </div>
  <div class="optiondiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the nth class easily from the `classList` of element object,

```
var x = $(".datacheck").find("div").get(0);
var nthClass = x.classList[1]
var res = nthClass.replace("customdataid_", "");
console.log(res); //305
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to finding last digit in class.

```js
var digit = $(".datacheck > :first").attr("class").match(/[\d]+$/g)[0];
console.log(digit);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="datacheck">
    <div class="classic_div_data customdataid_305">some values come here</div>
    <div class="optiondiv"></div>
</div>
```